# How to detected when user's stop scrolling - Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to hide a div when user scroll the page, and when stop scroll I want to show the div.

I'm using @HostListener but it fired only user scroll the page.

```
  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) 
  onScroll(event) {
    this.scroll = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.scroll = false;
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Comment: are you using angular material which sometimes block scroll event?

Comment: No, this is the first thing about scroll event in the project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To improve your current code, call `clearTimeout` when the `scroll` event is detected. It will prevent the div from showing up until you stop scrolling for the specified amount of time.

```
public scroll = false;
private timeout: number;

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event) {
  this.scroll = true;
  clearTimeout(this.timeout);
  this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    this.scroll = false;
  }, 300);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrc8tj) for a demo.

Answer (score 3):

You can use RxJs's [debouncetime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html) for this usecase.

```js
fromEvent(window, "scroll").pipe(
    tap(() => this.scroll = true),
    debounceTime(100)
).subscribe(() => {
    this.scroll = false;
});
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dumymv

Answer (score 0):

Your approach works. And this Stackblitz proves it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5xcm6h

You may have an error somewhere else.

Comment: Explain. Your success condition is to 'hide a div when user scrolls, and show after stopping'. This condition has been met. However, if you want **near-instant** state changes, set the timeout to be 0ms instead of 2000ms.

Comment: Are you trying to scroll programmatically?

Comment: The div has an animation that slide the div off the screen, its work fine at first sight, but when I scroll to long or do a slow scroll, the div is popping up.